# JQuery Datepicker needs to fire onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, uidatepicker

I need to fire the jquery datepicker from a link click. Right now if i click on the textbox the datepicker opens which is great but i have a button next to the textbox that someone can click and it needs to open the datepicker next to it. Also I would like a label instead of a textbox, is that possible. The code is below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#mydate").datepicker({ maxDate: '+1y', minDate: new Date() });
```

});

```
   <li class="quick_date"><%= text_field_tag "mydate", Date.now.strftime('%m/%d/%Y'), :size => 10 %> <a id="quick_search" href="#">(Change Me)</a></li>
```

Comment: sorry there didnt even know about accept until u just said something....just accepted all the best answers...thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make the `#quick_search` link open the datepicker you can do this:

```
var mydate = $("#mydate").datepicker({ maxDate: '+1y', minDate: new Date() });
$("#quick_search").click(function(){
    mydate.datepicker("show");
});
```

Comment: thanks for that what about turning it from a textbox to a label is that possible

Comment: Why would you want to change the date of a `<label>`? If you really want to do that you can use the `onSelect` event.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
.datepicker({ showOn: 'button'})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// datefields
$('.datefield').click(function(e){
var datefield = $(this).datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
 }).unbind('blur focus');
datefield.datepicker('show');
});
```